# Running TensorFlow official CNN example error: ImportError: cannot import name 'cifar10'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

An error happened when I runing the [TensorFlow official CNN example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn).

```
$ python cifar10_train.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10
ImportError: cannot import name 'cifar10'
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll locally
```

I download `tensorflow` zip files from `Github` and run `python cifar10_train.py` in `tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably downloaded the unstable master version.

I recommend you to reinstall TensorFlow as explained in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/), and try again.